# Get NSIS Variable for %ALLUSERSPROFILE%

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

Is there a NSIS variable for `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`?

If not do you know how I can obtain this environment variable using NSIS code?

**Note:** If I use `ReadEnvStr $R7 "ALLUSERSPROFILE"`, `$R7` contains `C:/ProgramData` because the installer has requested elevated privileges (`RequestExecutionLevel  admin`). This is sooo frustrating!

Comment: What folder are you expecting to get?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UAC/elevations since you are asking about a folder that is shared by all users...

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Vista %ALLUSERSPROFILE% is %SystemDrive%\ProgramData. Some of the things that used to be under All Users was moved to %Public% and the rest is in %ProgramData%.

There are several ways to get this directory but they should all give you the same answer:

```
ReadEnvStr $0 "ALLUSERSPROFILE"
DetailPrint %ALLUSERSPROFILE%=$0


System::Call 'userenv::GetAllUsersProfileDirectory(t.r0,*i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.r1'
DetailPrint GetAllUsersProfileDirectory=$0


; In Vista+ %ALLUSERSPROFIL% and CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA is the same directory:
SetShellVarContext all
DetailPrint All:Appdata=$AppData


!define FOLDERID_ProgramData {62AB5D82-FDC1-4DC3-A9DD-070D1D495D97}
System::Call 'shell32::SHGetKnownFolderIDList(g"${FOLDERID_ProgramData}", i0x1000, i0, *i.r1)i.r0'
${If} $0 == 0
    System::Call 'shell32::SHGetPathFromIDList(ir1,t.r0)'
    System::Call 'ole32::CoTaskMemFree(ir1)'
    DetailPrint SHGetKnownFolderIDList=$0
${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Anders reply, you could also use *SHGetSpecialFolderPath* and make a simple one line call to receive the path to a folder on the operating system.

---

```
System::Call 'shell32::SHGetSpecialFolderPath(i $HWNDPARENT, t .r1, i 0x23, i0)i.r0'
```

---

Use it with **CSIDL Values**, and you can simply call a function and pop the return.

```
Function ".OnInit"
  System::Call 'shell32::SHGetSpecialFolderPath(i $HWNDPARENT, t .r1, i 0x23, i0)i.r0'
  pop $1
  MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "$1"
FunctionEnd

Section ""
  ; blank section (so the script runs)
SectionEnd
```

This will return *C:\ProgramData (Vista+)* or *C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data (XP)* into **$1** and display a Message Box showing the path.

By switching up the CSIDL Value (*0x23*) you can return the path to a bunch of different system folders.

---

Here are some common CSIDL Values that you can use to return the path:

- 0x0 Desktop
- 0x2 Programs
- 0x5 My document
- 0x6 Favorites
- 0x7 Startup
- 0x8 Recent documents
- 0x9 Sendto documents
- 0x10 Desktop Directory
- 0x11 My Computer
- 0x14 Fonts directory
- 0x15 Windows Template
- 0x20 Internet Cache
- 0x21 Cookies
- 0x22 History
- 0x23 Common Application Data
- 0x25 System
- 0x26 Program Files
- 0x27 My Pictures
- 0xb StartMenu
- 0xd My Music
- 0x1a Application Data
- 0x1c Local Application Data
- 0x2b Common Program Files

---

Comment: The native NSIS constants use SHGetSpecialFolderPath behind the scenes.